# How to hide the transition searchBar next screen

Tags: ios, swift

Added The Search bar TableView, but when one of the items that were looking for and the transition to his page SearchBar and module  typing is not removed and remains on the screen. How can we make the transition to searchbar module typing cleaned?

[image]

Comment: Have you used `UISearchController` ?

Answer (score 0):

If Have you have used `UISearchController`,put `viewWillDisappear:` in viewController.

```
//this is my searchController, created programatically
var searchController : UISearchController?;

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated);

        if let sc = self.searchController where sc.active {
            self.searchController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil);
        }
    }
```

Reason : 
`UISearchController` is subclass of `UIViewController`.
If your search bar is `active`, that means it over your current viewController. so before going out from your viewController you need to check if it is `active` or not, by using its property `.active`.